# Stash get within the same set

Tags: stash, parse-order

Can't quite figure this one out. Trying to set and then get "program_sponsor" within stash:content

program_sponsor is returning blank with stash:get

```
{exp:stash:set parse_tags="yes" parse_conditionals="yes"}
    {exp:switchee variable="{segment_2}"}
        {case default="yes"}
            {stash:content}
                {exp:channel:entries channel="programs" url_title="{segment_2}" dynamic="no" limit="1"}
                    {stash:program_sponsor}
                        <p>Who loves bacon?</p>
                    {/stash:program_sponsor}
                {/exp:channel:entries}

                {!-- 
                    chunck of other channel entry code goes in-between here
                --}

                {!-- Need to output this variable set earlier above --}
                {exp:stash:get name="program_sponsor"}

            {/stash:content}
        {/case}
    {/exp:switchee}
{/exp:stash:set}
```

Comment: Try `parse_depth="2"` on your `{exp:stash:set}` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried parse="inward" on the switchee tag which caused nothing to return.

Also tried parse_depth="2" on the exp:stash:set tag.

To fix this I stripped out the stash:program_sponsor from stash:content and made more separation rather than setting a stash variable within a variable expecting then to grab it later in the same variable.

I changed my layout to include all the individual variables. What I was hoping to accomplish is narrow everything down to 1 variable which would have been stash:content.